# home network with more than 255 devices

Tags: networking, router, subnet

I have a pretty crazy home network, with 1 main asus router and 4 asus routers commissioned as access points. I also have 3 24 port switches and 6 8 port switches.
I want to allow devices to sit on the 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.2.255 address space.

I thought it would be as simple as setting the netmask to 255.255.252.0 on all my router/access points - but it doesn't seem to work.
I have manually assigned a test device (which has a web interface) to 192.168.2.50, but when I try access its web page in a browser from a host pc on 192.168.1.200, it just times out.

A tracert fails. So, I must be missing some basic understanding of how to get this all working and would appreciate pointers/solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: There is probably some device somewhere that has the wrong netmask. Check to make sure every device has the right netmask.

Comment: The set up in your question seems valid. Check if there is anything inconsistent with what you described

Comment: Thanks...anyone know of a more sophisticated tool that can help diagnose where it's all breaking down? The PC and the test device both have the right netmask.

Comment: Check your router's documentation to see how large of a LAN network it can support.  Often, SOHO equipment is limited to a LAN of /24, for no good reason, other than to encourage up-selling to a pricier  business-class device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the setup should work but some of the hardware may not be capable of CIDR due to hard coding and as such is borking when you pull the bitmask lower than 24 on a 192.168.x.0 network.

Consider readdressing to a routine RFC1918 network such as the 172.16.0.0/16 network and try testing using that.

Alternatively nmap and wireshark will help to work out whats going on.